# jquery checkbox html problems

Tags: jquery, html

I'm facing some problems with some jQuery or HTML.

I have some checkboxes. And I want to have a "primary" checkbox so a few checkboxes under that category get checked when the "primary" gets checked.

Well, that's OK. I solved it like this:

```
    $('#extraPolish').change(function() {
    if ($("#extraPolish").is(':checked') == true) {
        $("#extraPolish_Inside").attr('checked', 'checked');
        $("#extraPolish_UnderFender").attr('checked', 'checked');
        $("#extraPolish_OverFender").attr('checked', 'checked');
        console.log('checkd');
    } else {
        $("#extraPolish_Inside").removeAttr('checked');
        $("#extraPolish_UnderFender").removeAttr('checked');
        $("#extraPolish_OverFender").removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

So when you check #extraPolish those under there get checked, and when you remove check on #extraPolish those will be unchecked.

The problem is when i try to check them again it shows in the HTML code, but won't get checked on my Google Chrome.

Any Idea?

Comment: could you link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Only fails on Google Chrome?  Please add a Google Chrome tag.

Comment: What if you use $('#checkboxid').checked = $('#extraPolish').checked ? Saves an if statement.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rc9wC/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xxLLu/

Comment: I dont understand why it works on yours and not mine, j08691?

Comment: @Kristian - looks like we used different versions of jQuery in our examples.

Comment: Aha. So that means i have to use jQuery 1.8.3, or is there another solution @j08691?

Comment: @Kristian - no need to stay with 1.8.3, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated - with jquery 1.9 `prop()` is the function you want .attr() does something different, missed that in the first place...

This would be my solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#extraPolish').change(function() {
        $("#extraPolish_Inside").prop('checked', this.checked);
        $("#extraPolish_UnderFender").prop('checked', this.checked);
        $("#extraPolish_OverFender").prop('checked', this.checked);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("#extraPolish_Inside').prop('checked', true);` and `$("#extraPolish_Inside').prop('checked', false);` instead of `$("#extraPolish_Inside").attr('checked', 'checked');`

Edit: jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/rvtvr/1

Answer (score 0):

In stead of totally removing the `checked` attribute, try setting it simply to null.

```
$('#extraPolish_Inside').attr('checked',null);
```

### [Here is a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Dph/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop('checked', false);` and `.prop('checked', true);` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#extraPolish').change(function() {
        if ($("#extraPolish").is(':checked') == true) {
            $("#extraPolish_Inside").prop('checked', true);
            $("#extraPolish_UnderFender").prop('checked', true);
            $("#extraPolish_OverFender").prop('checked', true);
            console.log('checkd');
        } else {
            $("#extraPolish_Inside").prop('checked', false);
            $("#extraPolish_UnderFender").prop('checked', false);
            $("#extraPolish_OverFender").prop('checked', false);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xxLLu/3/)**

See http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop- for a full explanation and why the behavior differs between jQuery 1.9 and earlier.